# Angular 8+ with apache wicket, possible mix?

Tags: angular, wicket

Is it possible to mix angular8+ with apache wicket?

```
No code
```

Comment: Possible? Sure. Is it a good idea? Probably not.

Comment: @MikeOne, thank you for answer, did you try it or know how possible could be by sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible!

Wicket could produce one part of a web page and Angular/React/Vue/... the rest.
You can use Wicket Ajax APIs if you want to update the Wicket component tree from your Angular code.

If you ask more specific questions then we will be able to give you more specific answers.

Comment: Could you please give an example ? Thx!

Comment: Sorry, no! I don't have any example that I could share.